# Unable to configure the Docker daemon with file (Configuration file

Tags: docker, unix, dockerfile, nvidia, docker-machine

I am new to docker and trying to run rootless containers with nvidia runtime. However, I am not able to run it due to the below error as shown in screenshot below

[image]

My config file looks like as shown below

[image]

I have created a configuration file (config.json) with data root parameter and have placed this file under "config" folder and have updated this path in the 'Taskfile.yml' file. But still for some reason, it throws error as no such file or directory. Can you please help me with this? Am new and just getting my hands dirty with this. The below code indicates the update that I made in Taskfile.yml file

```
dockerd:
  cmds:
    - ./boot/dockerd.sh --config- 
file="/data/volume02/selva/usernetes/config/config.json"
```

I would expect to be able to run the docker server without any error.

Comment: can you share `dockerd.sh` file ?

Comment: there is no comma `,` at the end of command.

Comment: No, I didn't include ",". It's part of the syntax. I am just providing you screenshot

Comment: updated config file screenshot

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van How to kill a process with a specifc id?

Comment: `kill -9 id_number`

Comment: My pid is 1009, when I try to kill using "kill 1009" or "kill -9 1009", it doesn't work. What can be the reason. It throws an error message that "failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /run/user/1009/docker.pid"

Comment: which user did you do ? and which process_id owner ?

Comment: I fixed it. 1009 was the user id.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan - Can you please help me with the below error? I guess this is something to do with cgroups "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"process_linux.go:407: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"fork/exec /data/volume02/selva/usernetes/bin/nvidia-container-runtime-hook: exec format error\\\"\"": unknown."

Comment: Ignore it, docker deamon run fine.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan - The above error doesn't let me run Nvidia platform.. Am trying to run rootless container with nvidia runtime. Is it because of cgroups? I fixed that cgroup issue by creating a config.toml file and providing the absolute path of config.toml file in nvidia-container-runtime-hook file

Comment: After fixing the above error, I would like to execute the below command successfully. "export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock"
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm -it nvidia/cuda:10.0-devel nvidia-smi"... Currently I receive the above error after executing the above export command

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan - Can you please look into the below issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676574/unable-to-run-rootless-containers-via-nvidia-runtime . Would be very helpful